# Run Database Query on Link Click and still load the link URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax, coldfusion

**Question: Is it possible to trigger a database query via an `<a>` tag and still send the visitor to the url of the `<a>`?**

My first thought is to have a page that every link goes to and that page will save the URL of the link but before redirecting the user to that links url run a query that pushes the url to a database among other Session information and once the query is successful then send the person to the URL.

Is there a better way to accomplish this task possibly with AJAX or JQuery?

The page is written in ColdFusion.

Comment: If these links are to pages in your ColdFusion site, you could run the query from your onRequestStart() function of your Application.cfc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a .cfm file that all links go through and in that cfm file you can log or record that click into a db.  Coldfusionbloggers.org does something similar to this.   What you are thinking is good.   I wouldn't use ajax for this I don't think.

Comment: +1 for not using ajax as you wouldn't be able to record non JS enabled visitors

Comment: Thanks for confirming and the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in OnRequestStart() for application.cfc--or, if you're still using Application.cfm, just early in the file so it's before as much as possible...

You could do it in one table and store the data as JSONSerialization. I d

```
<cfquery>
    INSERT INTO SavedInfo(userID,page_url,qs,scopedump)
    VALUES(<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#session.userID#">,
        <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_nvarchar" value="#cgi.script_name#">,
        <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_nvarchar" value="#cgi.query_string#">,
        <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_nvarchar" value="#SerializeJSON(session)#">)
</cfquery>
```

Notes:

- This is a simple demonstration, there are other custom JSON solutions, you may rather use those than CF's built in JSON.
- I hope that you're hashing, or at least encrypting, your passwords. If you are not, start doing that immediately, and make sure the raw password is not visible in this data. Noone, even the site's developer, should see raw user passwords.
- I'd also include a datetime, and let my database autofill that with a default value.
- I'd put some limitations on this so that it only tracked in certain folders (or didn't track in certain folders.

And then, on a display page, you can list out

```
<cfquery name="GetList">
select UserID,page_url,qs
  from SavedInfo
 order by dumpID desc
</cfquery>
```

It's usually good to not just generically select * in such a situation, but here it's especially good. You could soon be outputting thousands of rows and you don't need the hunk of data that is scopedump coming with every row.

Link the results to a page that shows the scopedump and uses

```
<cfquery name="GetDump">
select *
  from SavedInfo
 where DumpID = <cfqueryparam type="cf_sql_integer" value="#url.dumpID#">
</cfquery>

<cfoutput query="GetDump">#Userid#, #page_url#?#qs#, etc...
  <cfset as_cf = DeSerializeJSON(scopedump)>
  <cfdump var="#as_cf#">
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: The only problem is and I should have stated this in my question is not all links point to pages on my server some take the user off site so I wouldn't be able to trigger the application.cfm file.

Comment: You could either use the query as I posted in an `/r.cfm?d=#urlecodedformat("linkandquerystringhere")#` or you could use jQuery to do an AJAX post. Here's a simple example http://jsfiddle.net/xcr56gd1/ or you could use a combination of both and strip out the /r.cfm? if jquery is enabled. So it looks cleaner and doesn't send most users through r.cfm.